Can an offgrid inverter work directly from the MPPT charge controllers, without batteries?
I have a 17kW capacity solar panel system, split into 4 divisions, each one connected to a Victron MPPT charge controller.
Also, I have a 6000VA Victron offgrid inverter.
On a bright, cloudless day, it would be possible to use the offgrid system without any batteries?
If not, why? There is a risk to damage any of the components?
Thank you!

Theoretically possible? probably. Practically possible? Certainly not. Any variation in the sun or load would cause huge problems.

why not just ad a small (eg 20AH) battery to each?

Of course there will be a proper battery bank. I just was curios, more like a theoretical question, not an implementable one.

These MPPT chargers have a constant current output to charge a battery. They're not designed to output a steady voltage, rather to adapt to whatever voltage the battery is at. And the inverter wants a constant voltage input and to be able to pull as much current as it needs without voltage dropping. So, they're not compatible, in fact, they're opposite.
I dont' think there's a risk of damage: if no battery is connected the chargers should simply shut down and report an error, and the inverter won't work. I doubt Victron would sell a MPPT charger that blows up when no battery is connected.
It could be possible to replace the batteries with a huge capacitor bank, if the chargers accept to begin charging at zero volts, which they will probably refuse to do. A discharged capacitor looks like a short, and if the charger is smart it will detect it and report an error.
Note it is not really possible to convert from PV to AC single or dual phase, and use the full capacity of the panels, without some form of energy storage. This is because AC power is pulsed, when voltage is at its peak power is maximum, but when voltage is near zero so is power. Meanwhile PV produces DC. So all PV inverters have a (usually quite large) heap of capacitors to bridge the gap. It's the same principle as the storage caps in a AC to DC power supply, in the other direction. It would be possible with three phase, because three phase power is not pulsed.
Some PV inverters do what you want, I think Fronius Primo Gen24 does it with the PV Point option. They're all-in-one units, so the high voltage from PV goes through the MPPT and into a capacitor bank, which is also the high voltage DC rail for the inverter. Of course this is quite limited, if your load consumes more power than PV provides then it will shut down. So if your load is significant it will shut down every time a cloud passes by. This is inconvenient, which is why this feature is quite rare.

To regulate the PV for maximum power transfer, the PC voltage must be adjusted to match the solar power input or essentially match impedances.  However, AC Inverters need a low ESR battery impedance to provide good load regulation e.g. 1% such that the battery and switching circuit resistance must be < 1% of the output load to provide this. Otherwise, the voltage would fail to be constant with every load change on and off. Trying to regulate a lower impedance than the source would cause the MPPT control to not transfer power efficiently with too much load on the high-impedance panels.
There are PV inverters without batteries but the low impedance comes from the grid (GTI's) and the current is sourced as a unity power factor sine wave at a regulated power up to the max available.  GTI's offer more features with complexity but have tighter requirements and protections up and downstream to be certified for connection to the grid.
Some companies use micro-grid inverters that may use ultracaps for low-impedance storage. These can then be shared or combined. This does not store much energy beyond 1 sine wave at full power as ultracaps have much lower energy density than batteries.
